# How Do I Click This Button? In Visual Basic 2010 WebBrowser control

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to click this button in WebBrowser Control

[image]

Im trying to make a web automation to purchase from gamestop im using visual basic 2010 express heres what my code looks like
Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mainContentPlaceHolder_dynamicContent_ctl00_RepeaterResultFoundTemplate_ResultFoundPlaceHolder_1_ctl00_1_ctl00_1_StandardPlaceHolderTop_3_ctl00_3_rptResults_3_res_0_btnAddToCart_0").InvokeMember("Click")

End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.gamestop.com/browse?nav=16k-3-wwii,28zu0")
End Sub


Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("cartcheckoutbtn").InvokeMember("Click")
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("buyasguest").InvokeMember("Click")
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ShipTo_FirstName").SetAttribute("value", "Rob")
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ShipTo_LastName").SetAttribute("value", "Horton")
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ShipTo_City").SetAttribute("value", "San Diego")
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("USStates").InvokeMember("Select")
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ShipTo_Line1").SetAttribute("value", "9295 PebbleStone Ln")
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ShipTo_PostalCode").SetAttribute("value", "92128")
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ShipTo_PhoneNumber").SetAttribute("value", "6194682282")
    For Each ee As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.All
        If ee.InnerText Is Nothing Then Continue For
        If ee.InnerText = "California" Then ee.SetAttribute("Selected", True)
    Next
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ShipTo_EmailAddress").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
    For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        If element.GetAttribute("class") = "btn_positive ats-checkoutbtn" Then
            element.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next







End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
```

Im trying to click on this button and i inspect elemented it and this is what showed up **

> (CONTINUE CHECKOUT ▶)

**
How Do I make it click this i tried Id but it has no id
btw im new to this just trying to make a auto web automation software to purchase games The code thats there when i inspect element it is on the top top top

Answer (score 0):

You are actually trying to click a link and not an input button.

The link has an `onclick` attribute that contains javascript and returns false.

So you can either find that link or you can just execute the Javascript that the link executes `submitshipto()`

```
WebBrowser1.InvokeScript("submitshipto()")
```

Or:

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
    If element.GetAttribute("class") = "btn_positive ats-checkoutbtn" Then
        element.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
Next
```